# Entity Framework, Inheritance and condition by Navigation Property

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have three entities in entity framework. First - BaseEntity, and two derivede Foo1 and Foo2. So condition for splitting which is some int value field. If it has null value, than it is a Foo2 entity, otherwise it is a Foo1 entity object. Foo1 also has a navigation property which reference to that some field.
So where should I define field in Base Entity or in Foo1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not map a discriminator column for a navigational property. Suppose you load a Foo1 entity and set that navigational property to null, this would change the meaning of `Foo1` to `Foo2`.

You will have to use separate column for the navigational property.

Comment: Ok. thank you! But in my case it is imposible set this navigation property (get; private set;)...

Comment: Still discriminator columns are not allowed. Reflections API will allow you to modify private setters.